# Ray Serve Can't Create Backend

Tags: ray

I'm getting a strange error when trying to run a basic ray program.

```
import ray
from ray import serve
import time

ray.init()

# This will start Ray locally and start Serve on top of it.
serve.start()

def my_backend_func(request):
  return "hello"

serve.create_backend("my_backend", my_backend_func)
```

Running this gives me the following error: `AttributeError: module 'ray.serve' has no attribute 'create_backend'`.

If I store the object created by calling `serve.start()` in a variable, and use that to call `.create_backend` instead of `serve` it works. Every single test case, example, etc. does not do this so I was wondering what I might be doing wrong. I was able to recreate this issue on every Linux machine I tried it on, and in both python3.6 and python3.8. Thank you!

Comment: Following the documentation, `client = serve.start()` is how this should start, and then you use the `client` object to initialize the backend.... is there a reason you've written your code differently than this?

Comment: @OuyangZe the reason I've written my code this way is that I am trying to follow all of the examples, tutorials, etc. which are given on the GitHub repo and various other sources online. By looking through the source code I figured out that doing the "client" method works, but I wasn't sure if I was doing some sort of hack solution.

Comment: No problem-- it is currently not very windows friendly either, according to [this](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/installation.html#windows-support), which I've found uot the hard way too.  Seems like a cool project though, docs could use some work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone in the future has this issue, here is the answer:

You are running the older stable release 1.2.0 which comes by default when you install ray with pip. All of the examples listed on the Github repo, and the source code/tests I was looking at are running the newer 2.0.0 version which you must [download in a different way](https://docs.ray.io/en/master/installation.html#daily-releases-nightlies).